# External content types in sharepoint

Tags: bcs, external-content-type

I have an external list based webpart with 5 wild card filters. when I searched using one filter the required item is displayed but the same item is not displayed using other filter. For example if an item has last name JOhnson and title Project Manager, when an item is searched using last name item is displayed but when searched using title item is not displayed. Can any one help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SPD, or just the filter in the OOTB browser?  Maybe there is some case sensitivity, or your filter have AND/OR added improperly.  You need to add more details to help troubleshoot.